# uitabbarcontroller has a navigationbar

Tags: ios

I have a uitabbarcontroller with four uiviewcontrollers. And I also have a custom uinavigationbar. I want to the custom uinavigationbar fixed on top of all four uiviewcontrollers.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|     custom  navigationbar fixed like header    |
--------------------------------------------------
|                                                |
|                                                |
|  if user select uitabbar items, only chage     |
|  view here, the navigation header fixed,not    |  
|  change.                                       |
|                                                |
--------------------------------------------------
|      here is uitatbar                          |
|________________________________________________|
```

Can anybody help me or give me any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Next time, please attatch an actual screenshot.  And I need you to be a bit more specific.  I am going to assume you are using Interface Builder.  So this is what I understand: a UINavigationBar at the top, a UITabBar at the bottom, and UIViews in the middle that are affected by the tab bar (but not the Navigation Bar)

Comment: yes. That's Purpose. How should I implement like that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can approach this:

- If you don't mind the tab bar disappearing when view controllers get pushed onto the navigation stack, simply make your `UITabBarController` the root view of your `UINavigationController`.
- Alternatively, if you want the tab bar to be persistent, use the `UITabBarController` as your root view and embed each of its views in a `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it will be easier in this case to use custom `UIViews` rather than `UIViewControllers` for the stuff in the middle.  You will have one `UIViewController` that contains the two bars and the stuff in between.  When the `UITabBar changes something, it will call a method in the viewController that calls a method in the UIView.

I can be more specific if you give me more info on what you are doing with the Tab Bar and UIViews.